What is the reference for this shloka?
I found out about the Besangar inscription on which some sanskrit shlokas are written. According to Wikipedia, they belong to Mahabharata

The second inscription on the pillar, in the same script, recites a
verse from the Hindu epic Mahabharata:[22][26]
Line 1. (These?) three steps to immortality, when correctly followed,
Line 2. lead to heaven: control, generosity, and attention.


Heliodorus pillar

Please give exact refrence for this shloka.

The sloka given in the wiki link is this -

Trini amutapādāni (i me) (su)anuthitāni
neyamti sva(gam) dama cāga apramāda

This sloka is similar to a sloka from the BORI edition of the Stri-parva (11th parva) 7.19 of Mahabharata.

tasmAnmaitraM samAsthAya shIlamApadya bhArata |
damastyAgo.apramAdashcha te trayo brahmaNo hayAH || 19||

